# Row-wise expansion of data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I basically want do the opposite of `ddply(df, columns.to.preserve, numcolwise(FUNCTION)`.

Suppose I have

```
d <- data.frame(
  count=c(2,1,3),
  summed.value=c(50,20,30),
  averaged.value=c(35,80,20)
)

      count summed.value averaged.value
1     2           50             35
2     1           20             80
3     3           30             20
```

I want to do a row expansion of this data.frame based on the `count` column while specifying what kind of operation I want to apply to the other columns.
Here is the kind of result I'm looking for:

```
> d2
  count summed.value averaged.value
1     1           25             35
2     1           25             35
3     1           20             80
4     1           10             20
5     1           10             20
6     1           10             20
```

Any there built in functions within `dplyr` or other packages that does this kind of operation?

**Edit**: This is different from the [`De-aggregate / reverse-summarise / expand a dataset in R`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208529/de-aggregate-reverse-summarise-expand-a-dataset-in-r) question because I want to go further and actually apply different functions to columns within the table I wish to expand. There are also more useful and answers on this post.

Comment: Some places to start on expanding the data.frame [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208529/de-aggregate-reverse-summarise-expand-a-dataset-in-r).  Once that is done, just divide `summed.value` and `count` by `count`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `dplyr` and `tidyr`, you can do a `rowwise` transformation for the `summed.value` which produces a list for each cell and then `unnest` the column should give you what you need:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
d %>% rowwise() %>% summarise(summed.value = list(rep(summed.value/count, count)), 
                              averaged.value = averaged.value, count = 1) %>% unnest()

# Source: local data frame [6 x 3]

#   averaged.value count summed.value
#            <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1             35     1           25
# 2             35     1           25
# 3             80     1           20
# 4             20     1           10
# 5             20     1           10
# 6             20     1           10
```

Another way is to use `data.table`, where you can specify the row number as group variable, and the data table will automatically expand it:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)
d[, .(summed.value = rep(summed.value/count, count), averaged.value, count = 1), .(1:nrow(d))]
 [, nrow := NULL][]

#   summed.value averaged.value count
#1:           25             35     1
#2:           25             35     1
#3:           20             80     1
#4:           10             20     1
#5:           10             20     1
#6:           10             20     1
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a function `untable` in package *reshape* for getting the inverse of a table.  Then divide the variables that need dividing by `count` via `mutate_at` (or `mutate_each`).  `mutate_at` was introduced in *dplyr_0.5.0*.

First the `untable`:

```
library(reshape)
untable(d, num = d$count)

    count summed.value averaged.value
1       2           50             35
1.1     2           50             35
2       1           20             80
3       3           30             20
3.1     3           30             20
3.2     3           30             20
```

Then the `mutate_at` for dividing `summed.value` and `count` by `count`:

```
library(dplyr)

untable(d, num = d$count) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(summed.value, count), funs(./count))

  count summed.value averaged.value
1     1           25             35
2     1           25             35
3     1           20             80
4     1           10             20
5     1           10             20
6     1           10             20
```

Comment: Where does `mutate_at` come from? It doesn't appear to be in `plyr` or `dplyr`. Also, do you happen to know why `untable` isn't in `reshape2`?

Comment: `mutate_at` is in the current version of dplyr.  I don't know why `untable` wasn't brought into reshape2.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a both simple and fully vecotrized base R approach

```
transform(d[rep(1:nrow(d), d$count), ], 
          count = 1, 
          summed.value = summed.value/count)
#     count summed.value averaged.value
# 1       1           25             35
# 1.1     1           25             35
# 2       1           20             80
# 3       1           10             20
# 3.1     1           10             20
# 3.2     1           10             20
```

Or similarly, using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
res <- setDT(d)[rep(1:.N, count)][, `:=`(count = 1, summed.value = summed.value / count)]
res
#    count summed.value averaged.value
# 1:     1           25             35
# 2:     1           25             35
# 3:     1           20             80
# 4:     1           10             20
# 5:     1           10             20
# 6:     1           10             20
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution: It tries to replicate each row by the value of the `count` column and then divide `count` and `summed.value` columns by `count`.

```
mytext <- 'count,summed.value,averaged.value
2,50,35
1,20,80
3,30,20'

mydf <-  read.table(text=mytext,header=T,sep = ",")

mydf <- do.call(rbind,apply(mydf, 1, function(x) {
  tempdf <- t(replicate(x[1],x,simplify = T))
  tempdf[,1] <- tempdf[,1]/x[1]
  tempdf[,2] <- tempdf[,2]/x[1]
  return(data.frame(tempdf))
}))

count summed.value averaged.value
     1           25             35
     1           25             35
     1           20             80
     1           10             20
     1           10             20
     1           10             20
```